# Getting "error" as null, even if the URL is not returning any data

Tags: javascript

In the below mentioned code, Couldn't able to handle the exception, even if the URL doesn't return any data, I am getting "error" as null.
Right now the URL is returning JSON data, but if i am providing wrong URL, I am getting exception.

```
const request = require("request");
const url =
  "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/4a923c69dc2f04fbf07d6f05a5c764c3/37.8267,-122.4233";
try {
  request({ url: url }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Check URL");
    } else {
      const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
      console.log(data.currently.temperature);
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Check URL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error will have the value whenever there is an error in fetching the data. So in the success case error will always has the null  value. You need to check the `data` and based on it you check that if the data is null or not.

You can also check the status code for error `response.statusCode`.

```
const request = require("request");
const url =
  "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/4a923c69dc2f04fbf07d6f05a5c764c3/37.8267,-122.4233";
try {
  request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Check URL");
    } else if(response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      const data = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(data.currently.temperature);
    } else {
        console.log('ERROR');
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Check URL");
}
```